# Use Java web start to start application on the command line by the file name

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I can use Java web start to start my Swing GUI application on the command line by the url with jdk 6 & Windows XP:
javaws http://localhost:7001/webstart/myapp/launch.jnlp

How to use Java web start to start my Swing GUI application on the command line by the file name?

The following ways do not work:
    javaws -codebase ''  launch.jnlp
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ''
    at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.parseArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
javaws -codebase "" launch.jnlp
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.parseArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

javaws -codebase "file:." launch.jnlp
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:./$$name
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

javaws -codebase "file:." file://launch.jnlp
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: file://launch.jnlp]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

javaws file://launch.jnlp 
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: file://launch.jnlp]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

#The following has no error message, but nothing appear on the computer screen:
javaws -codebase "" -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket launch.jnlp
javaws -J-Xdebug -J-Xnoagent -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y launch.jnlp
javaws -codebase "" -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=n launch.jnlp
javaws -codebase "" -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n launch.jnlp
```

The launch.jnlp file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="$$codebase" href="$$name"> 

  <information> 
    <title>${com.prod.my.myapp.common.client.title}</title> 
    <vendor>I</vendor> 
    <homepage href="http://devzone/english/dev%20template/html_templates/main.asp"/> 
    <description>${com.prod.my.myapp.common.client.description}</description> 
    <description kind="short">${com.prod.my.myapp.common.client.short_description}</description> 
    <icon href="$$context/images/chflag.jpg"/> 
  </information> 

  <security> 
      <all-permissions/> 
  </security> 

  <resources> 

  <java version="1.6.0_05" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" max-heap-size="256m"/> 

    <!-- myapp Application --> 
    <jar href="myprod.myapp.client.jar"/> 
    <jar href="myprod.reports.jar"/> 

    <!-- TR Client jar --> 
    <jar href="extern.ejb-client.jar"/> 

    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"/> 
    <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="${com.prod.my.myapp.common.client.naming_provider}"/> 
    <property name="weblogic.jndi.enableServerAffinity" value="true" / 

  </resources> 

  <application-desc main-class="com.prod.my.myapp.common.framework.applicationmainwindow.gui.myappAp­plication"/ 

</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a codebase value of..

```
"file:."
```

Comment: javaws -codebase "file:." launch.jnlp does not work.  See above for error message.

Comment: OK - now I look at your current output, it underlines that there are variables that are unresolved until the JNLP is fetched through the server.  The server fills in ('resolves') the extra details.  Unless you hard code those values, it will never work directly from the local file system.

Comment: How to save the extra details in a file or display to a console? Is there a "println" command?

Comment: The "extra details" are every attribute value starting with "$$".  Look at the source of the JNLP as produced by the browser (pull it into a JEditorPane if need be) and use those details for the 'offline' version.  BTW - what is the point of all this?  If you have a server that fills in the details at run-time, why not use it?

Comment: I ask this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851758/use-eclipse-to-run-an-existing-java-web-start-application and think that understanding the launch.jnlp file will achieve my goal of using Eclipse to debug my java web start Swing application.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your JNLP file should be used together with the [JNLPDownloadServlet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html). It replaces the `$$name` and `$$codebase` palceholders with the current values based on the server where you application currently runs. (Btw. you can also use `$$server` to refer the current server)

If you run it locally from disk, you can overwrite the `codebase` by setting it on the command line as parameter `-codebase`. The right value is `file:.`. You problem is that the `$$name` placeholder is not replaced and it tries do download the `<jnlp ... href="$$name">` which results to `file:.$$name` and since no such file exists it fails.

You can either completely omitt the `href="$$name"` attribute in the `<jnlp />` tag when running locally or manually change it to the jnlp file name e.g. `<jnlp ... href="myApp.jnlp" />`.

Also remeber if you want to use some local jar stored on you disk and you want to refer it via absolute path you should use this format `<jar href="file:c:/myJars/myJar.jar">` (forward slashes).

All the best.