# How to deploy jar both with Web Start and an installer?

Tags: java, deployment, jar, java-web-start

I have a Java desktop application and now we distribute it as a jar in a installer of a main application (currently the Java application is only an importer/exporter). But as the jar is updated more often than the main application we are thinking of making it run through Java Web Start so it's updated independently when it start.

My question is how can I distribute it in the installer so if the user don't have internet it use the jar bundle in the installer (and copied in the main application folder) but when he launch and have internet, Java Web Start update it?

*Edit:* I have think in making two JNLP files one for local launch and one for online launch so it get updated, but then they need to share the cached jar so isn't installed two times, and I don't know if this is possible.

*Edit, more explanations:*

Maybe I haven't explain it very well. I have a native application and is distributed as an MSI, from download and through CD. With this application we distribute the Java application (a jar) that the main application used to exchange data to other formats. The MSI installs both the native app and copy the jar (not really install). Now if the user have internet and a new update is published, the complete MSI is downloaded and installed (updating the installation). Ok?

Well, we like to update only the jar in a more fashion approach, with Java Web Start, so it's updated when the jar is run independently of the main app. This have the problem that if we only deploy it as Java Web Start, if the user install the app in a computer without internet (for example carrying the MSI in a pen-drive or cd) he will not be able to use it, because as he don't have internet he can't download the jar.

And now is when my question come, can I deploy the jar in the MSI but execute through a Java Web Start so if the user have internet it get updated but if he doesn't have internet it still can use the bundle jar in the MSI?

Comment: *"how can I distribute it in the installer"* How are you distributing the installer itself?

Comment: By CD or as a download in a msi, the users can install it in a machine without internet.

Comment: 1) *"or as a download.."*  What, with the internet the user does not have?  How does that work? 2) JWS is not practicable off CD.  It needs the internet or at least a network.  The only other option is a trusted applet on the CD to invoke the installer, and that would require an existing JRE. 3) I suspect it will cost more to support users with no internet, than the software sales made to those same people.

Comment: 1) Please, see the edit if it clear you questions. 2) You said something as using a local server? 3) Maybe, it's what I'm also starting to think that.

Comment: *"2) You said something as using a local server?"*  Yes I did.  IF there is, for example a 'company intranet' that all relevant machines can access, you might run a server, and be able to supply the JRE, app. & native all directly off that 'internal' server.  In that case, I cannot see the MSI adding anything to the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..can I deploy the jar in the MSI but execute through a Java Web Start so if the user have internet it get updated but if he doesn't have internet it still can use the bundle jar in the MSI?

OK, I am formulating a plan here, this *might* be doable.

Let us presume that the MSI is capable of doing the following things.

- Install a JRE if missing or too low a version available.  The JRE needs to be included in the MSI (to avoid requiring the net).
- Unpack the JWS launch file and Jar(s) (and native..) to the local file system as temporary files.
- Invoke the [javaws tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) using 'IMPORT-OPTIONS' to set the code-base to the place in the local file-system they were unpacked.

At this point, desktop icons and shortcuts should be installed, and the program ready to launch.  It is vital to specify a few extra options in the JNLP - specifically `offline-allowed` to ensure the app. can still be launched if the internet is not available.

**Caveats:**  I don't have any experience with MSI, and my experience with using the import options is limited to calling them from build files (during development).

Comment: I think this is what I need. I will try and said you if it solve the problem.

Comment: What I have observed is that if I use codebase attribute in the jnlp (put the online url) it overwrite codebase in command line and then it try to access internet to get the resources. If you let it blank then you can import it offline but after it have been imported it saved as if its url is local and jws don't try to update it online even if you also use -codebase with the online URL. I think this is a problem of the technology itself so maybe It can be solved (only with java web start). Anyway your answer is the more near to the solution. Must I accept it?

Comment: *"What I have observed is that if I use codebase attribute in the jnlp (put the online url) it overwrite codebase in command line and then it try to access internet to get the resources."*  It does not do that on my system.  When I am developing a new JWS app., it is not yet available on the net, but works by local import.

Comment: Maybe it be because I'm in linux? Will try on other system.

Comment: Finaly I have tryed it (mmm, a little late ;D). And think that maybe was linux or that I have wrong codebase uri format. Now I use `javaws.exe -import -codebase file:. mylauncher.jnlp` and it import correctly and then if launched as `javaws.exe mylauncher.jnlp` without internet it run, and if you have internet it upgrade! I have get the `file:.` clue in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4897626 answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)